# Verification of private method in JMockit

Tags: unit-testing, private, jmockit

I want to verify that a private method has been called in my JMockit test class. I don't want to mock the private method, only make sure it has been called.

Is this possible, and if so how?

(I found a similar question but there the private method was mocked, which I don't want if I can avoid it.)
Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
public class UnderTest {

  public void methodPublic(){
    .....
    methodPrivate(aStringList);
    .....
  }

  private void methodPrivate(List<String> slist){
    //do stuff
  }
}

public class TestMyClass {

  @Tested
  UnderTest cut;

  @Mocked
  List<String> mockList;

  @Test
  public void testMyPublicMethod() {

    cut.methodPublic();

    new Verifications() {
      {
        // this doesnt work for me...
        invoke(cut, "methodPrivate", mockList);
        times = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a partial mock (you cannot avoid mocking the private method in this instance if you wish to know if it was triggered or not - a verification can only be done on a mocked method or instance). I have not used JMockit before but I expect the code would look something similar to:

```
public class TestMyClass {

  @Tested
  UnderTest cut;

  @Mocked
  List<String> mockList;

  @Test
  public void testMyPublicMethod() {

    cut.methodPublic();

    new Expectations(UnderTest.class) {{
       cut.methodPrivate();
    }}

    new Verifications() {
      {
        // this should hopefully now work for you
        invoke(cut, "methodPrivate", mockList); //I assume here that you have statically imported the Deencapsulation class
        times = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting from answer: "a verification can only be done on a mocked method or instance". So, I "solved" it by actually calling the private method and then verify the result with assertEquals() (since some people one recommended not to mock the private methods). Another way would be to mock the private methods (as above) and only do Verifications(), which leaves the private methods untested...